# What does an arrow pointing up inside the staff mean?

Tags: notation

[image: upwards-pointing arrow]
This was in my audition music, and I can’t ask the person I got it from. It was written by the director at my high school.

Edit: Here’s the full music:
[image]
I’m not sure what style. 
Also, I can ask my director, but not for about a week and a half, which is why I asked here.

Comment: What instrument? What style? Can you post the full sheet?

Comment: The only thing I could find close to this was an arpeggio arrow, but the arrow is next to a chord. There is no chord next to this arrow, so it can't be that...Here's the link if you want to see it. https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/cmn/cmn/cmn.html#arrow

Comment: If this was written by your director - a. I'd ask them. b. I'd be concerned

Comment: Some thoughts building on Tim's comment. If I was a director and I was doing auditions I would not hold it against a player if they asked me about something in the piece they were auditioning with. If I explained it and they played it as I explained, all good. If they didn't ask and play it "wrong" I would maybe give the spot to the kid that asked and played it right. It's not like your asking what key the piece is in or what the time signature means. This doesn't seem like standard notation.

Comment: I think you might be right, Richard. I know how horrible Musescore is at handling notation. I’ll ask my director what it really is. Thanks!

Comment: @Richard - if that is indeed the case the director has some answering to do to retain any credence...

Comment: I agree with Richard. This is some sort of weird typo. Practice the rest of the piece. Play a half note there as a place holder for now and wait to get a good answer. Good luck on your audition.

Comment: I agree - printing/ notation error.

Answer (score 4):

I would say there's a strong possibility that this is a typeface error and this should just be a half-note G.

Notice that there is a note *stem* there, but there's no half-note note *head*. This arrow is not standard notation, so I'm wondering if the half-note note head got replaced by its closest symbol in another typeface.

Comment: I totally agree this is what happened.